# Changing element ClientId in repeater

Tags: asp.net

In asp.net repeater how can I change what unique id each element generated. Now it generates something like parent_repeater_ct001_controlinsiderepeater. What I would like to do is to replace this obscure ct001 to my value or even beter modify the whole id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't. I believe this will be possible in ASP.NET 4.0, but as for now, the IDs are generated. What is it you are trying to do?

Comment: Correct - you will only be able to do this in ASP.NET 4.0 - see http://weblogs.asp.net/asptest/archive/2009/01/06/asp-net-4-0-clientid-overview.aspx